# How do insert an Object using node.js to mysql table

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new to node.js and i have never worked with a server or a dataBase before, but im trying to learn.
So what i want to accomplish with this code is to take scores from CSV files from a folder, push them in a array of objects and store that object in a Mysql table. So far i have succeeded in getting the right scores from those CSV files, but what im having problms with is inserting that object to my Mysql table. It worked with normal array but i want to use object because its more clear i can read it easier. Here is my Nods.js code :

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const csv = require("csv-parser");
require('log-timestamp');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const app = express();

const scores = {
  Scenarios: "close",
  run_1: 1,
  run_2: 2,
  run_3: 3,
  run_4: 4,
  run_5: 5,
  run_6: 6,
  run_7: 7,
  run_8: 8,
  run_9: 9,
  run_10: 10,
};
const DELETE = "DELETE FROM complete_biginner";
const INSERT = "INSERT INTO complete_biginner VALUES (?)";

const co = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  host: 'localhost',
  password: 'nourmourad10',
  database: 'test',
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server is runnig");
})

const watcher = chokidar.watch('C:/Users/LolRandomXD/Desktop/games/KovaaKs.FPS.Aim.Trainer/KovaaKs.FPS.Aim.Trainer/FPSAimTrainer/stats/*.csv');

watcher.on('add', function(path) {
  console.log("Code is running");
  console.log('File', path, 'has been added');
  const results = [];

  fs.createReadStream(path)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on("data", (data) => results.push(data))
    .on("end", () => {

      const score = Math.floor(results[15].Timestamp);

      console.log(score);
    });

  // co.query(DELETE, (err, result) => {
  //     if(err) {
  //         console.log(err);
  //     }
  //     console.log(result);
  // })

  co.query(INSERT, [scores], (err, resule) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(resule);
  })
})
```

I hope i made my post clear, sorry if i didn't

Comment: Is `results` the data you want to put in the table? You're not doing anything with it.

Comment: I recommend that you use an ORM such as `Sequelize`. It's quite easier and more abstract.

Comment: @Barmar yes it is. I'm not using it yet. what im planing to do is push all the scores that i get into that array object. I just want to make sure that its goind to work before i start using it

Comment: If you're using an object as the source, I think you need to use `SET ?` rather than `VALUES (?)`. It will translate that into a series of `column = value` based on the keys and values in the object.

Comment: @Barmar is correct. Use `INSERT INTO table_name SET ?;` if you are providing an object which will correspond to the `?` in your query string. However this only works if you are inserting one record at a time. If you are inserting multiple records at once, you must provide column names and `VALUES()`. Also be mindful of how you will handle `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if there is the possibility of unique key conflicts.